# A probability inequality applying Feller-Chung lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $\{X_i,i\geq 1\}$ be independent r.v.'s with $E[X_i]=0$. Then prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is
\begin{equation*}
P\{\max_{1\leq j\leq n}S_j>\epsilon\}\leq 2P\{S_n\geq\epsilon-E|S_n|\}.
\end{equation*}

Applying Feller-Chung lemma with $A_j=\{S_j>\epsilon\},B_j=\{S_n-S_j>-E|S_n|\}$ we can obtain that
\begin{equation*}
P\{\max_{1\leq j\leq n}S_j>\epsilon\}\inf_{1\leq j\leq n}\{P[B_j]\}\leq P\{S_n\geq\epsilon-E|S_n|\}
\end{equation*}
But now the question is, how to show the term $\inf_{1\leq j\leq n}\{P[B_j]\}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ without information about higher order moment?

Comment: The inequality which you are trying to prove doesn't make sense to me. If we let $\epsilon \to \infty$, then the right-hand side converges to $0$ but the left-hand side does not (since it doesn't depend at all on $\epsilon$).

Comment: @saz Oh I am sooo sorry....the left term is also $\epsilon$ indeed

Comment: could you please remind me what this lemma says or give a link to its statement ?